# Replace everything between two character

Tags: bash, sed, awk

All.

I am newbie to sed.

I want something like

Input:

```
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO
```

Output:

```
ABC,,,,MNO
```

Means....

```
I want to remove all contents between two ','
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^,]*,/,/2g' file
```

Comment: thanks again... potong....    u also helped me in my last question. I can accept this after 10 min...so i will accept ur answer.... u r kool dude

Comment: but please....agian.... i am trying since 2-3 hours...but i cant....   can you explain why '/2' is required?? means can you explain in brief the whole syntax?

Comment: @user1640065 the substitute command can accept flags. The flags are set at the end of the command. In this case two flags are in operation. The `2` means replace the second occurrance, the `g` means replace all occurrances throughout the line. In combination they mean replace from the second to the last occurrance throughout the line (file).

Answer (score 3):

you could set all fields between 1 and last to empty with awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)$i=""}7'
```

Comment: @potong 's sed solution is simpler for this problem

Comment: @Endoro I like that number, that's it. you could use any number >0